# Which file size is smallest when we have same data?

Tags: file, memory-management, file-format

I have text document which contains more than 1000 pages. Can somebody help which file format(like doc, txt, .xml,etc), reduce the file size of that content(allocate small space for store the document)? Please help me..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Store it as a compressed text file. Text lends itself wonderfully to compression.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your platform, a compressed file (.zip, .arj, .gz) or similar will give you the smallest space requirement possible. Is that what you're looking for, or does the document also have to be human readable at the same time?